# Angular - Sidebar shows before navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have my sidebar in my app component. It only shows when the user is authenticated.

When I log my user in (I set auth to true). The sidebar shows up on the login page before it navigates to the protected route.

This is my app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<ngx-loading-bar></ngx-loading-bar>
<app-sidebar *ngIf="authService.isAuth"></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Can you post a typescript code from `app.component.ts`

Comment: I figured it out already. I just check if the router has ended.